# Android ExpandableListView with duplicate entries once a entry is expanded

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In the code for `ExpandableListView` implementation not having many entries and not scrollable as list is small, when an group is clicked, the expandable listview are populated with duplicate entries.

I am trying with kitkat version and I did check the adapter but could not get why it was populating with duplicate entries only after  expansion and collapse of the list. This issue gets solved if we hit home button and then go back to the activity.

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: How is this different from your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870061/expandablelistview-fills-with-duplicate-entries-if-display-screen-size-is-greate

Answer (score 1):

Inside onGroupClickListener for onGroupClick, set return type to true...

@Override

public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

return true;

}